# Finding limit distribution $T_n$

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_{2n}$ is a random sample of $N(0,1)$. If $D_n=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n X_{i}^2$ and $R_n=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{X_{2i-1}}{X_{2i}}$ and 
$T_n=\displaystyle\frac{R_n}{D_n}$, what is the limit distribution of $T_n$?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question] on Math.SE which has received two down votes.

Comment: I think independence is assumed when he says they are samples.

Comment: Apologies for not putting in the link in my previous comment. The Math.SE question is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/133853/15941).

Comment: And would you mind adding some motivations? Why are you interested in such a quantity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can recognize that $R_n$ is the sum of $n$ independent Cauchy variables.  $D_n$ is $\chi^2$ with $n$ degrees of freedom. (not sure but maybe for $D_n$ you meant for the sum to go to $2n$).  So $T_n$ is the ratio of the sum of independent Cauchy's to a $\chi^2$.

I don't know what that works out to be.  It appears complicated unless the numerator simplifies by some trick. As no one has tried to answer this one I thought I would at least mention what I know.

**Hint**: Divide the numerator and denominator by $n$ and consider each separately for a moment. What can you say about the numerator now as $n \to \infty$? What can you say about the denominator? Use a standard theorem in probability theory to conclude.

Comment: The reason this question has not been answered more likely has to do with how homework questions are treated on this site and the lack of communication and interaction on the part of the OP. The FAQ contains some relevant detail on what is expected from both questioners and answerers of homework.

Comment: Also, the quantity $R_n$ is a sum of *independent* standard Cauchy random variables and dividing both the numerator and denominator of $T_n$ by $n$ can rather easily be seen to yield the result.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I thought that one term in Rn was X1/X2 and the next X2/X3 but looking carefully at the indexing the consecutive terms X1/X2 and then X3/X4. so that makes the problem much easier than what I first thought.  Isn't it also a mistake to sum only up to n rather than 2n in the definition of Dn?  So is it common for students to use this site to get help with their homework problems?  Do we generally decide that if it looks suspiciously like a homework problem we don't answer it?

Comment: I can only speak for me, but my approach is that if they are stuck at a specific point and have laid out their approach I usually help them. If it's "I don't know how to approach this" I try to give a hint instead of a solution.

Comment: Michael, I suspected this might have been where the "dependent" claim in your answer arose. I'd encourage you to simply edit your post to make any corrections you deem appropriate. I'm not sure if $D_n$ was meant to sum up to $n$ or $2n$. I can see arguments both ways. If the point was to have something that has a "canonical" limiting distribution with no rescaling necessary, then using $n$ is sensible. but, it's definitely a bit weird from the perspective of "throwing away" half the random variables in the denominator.

Comment: Homework [gets special treatment](http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq) and full solutions are generally discouraged, but helpful hints are (very) welcome. We generally expect to see some effort from questioners to show what they've done and where they are stuck. This is to prevent the site from simply becoming a homework-solution repository. If users post verbatim homework questions with no attempt at elaboration, it usually ends up either ignored or downvoted, particularly if the behavior is repetitive. Homework should also be tagged `homework` so that others know to treat it as such.

Comment: I have edited the answer to add a (hopefully) useful hint, related to my second comment.